# Best way to read oracle number from stored procedure into a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a number of stored procedures, and I've been trying to find the best way to get an int in C# out of a stored procedure out parameter. So does anyone have advice on the best way to do this? Also, in some of the procedures the returned value can be null, so using nullable ints for them would be preferred. I have been doing it like this, but is there a better way? (Also, this is how I'm dealing with nulls currently, since 0 isn't a valid result for those procedures)

```
int sequence = 0;
int.TryParse(comm.Parameters["osequence"].Value.ToString(), out sequence);
```

Basically I am wondering if there is a way to cast without having to parse. I had been trying but eventually gave up and settled with this, since it seems to work.

Comment: What's the type of `comm.Parameters`?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are doing it the best way.  I don't know if using something like Dapper or Massive would gain you the "auto" mapping to the data type correctly or not, but you may want to give it a try.